Storing S3 data to be crawled by Glue and queried with Athena
I have some user activity data and want to be able to query it by userId, companyId and/or date. Do I have to replicate the data myself in S3 in 3 different partitions for each of the above or can I just store it by date and then have a crawler index it?
